# How do I return JSON from my Azure Storage Queue?

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I have a logic app that puts JSON in a queue.

[image]

Couldn't be more simple. But then, when I use the trigger for new messages, the raw output shows this:

```
    "body": {
        "MessageId": "e705a261-f2c4",
        "InsertionTime": "Tue, 02 Apr 2019 14:22:24 GMT",
        "ExpirationTime": "Tue, 09 Apr 2019 14:22:24 GMT",
        "PopReceipt": "AgAAAAMAAAAAA=",
        "TimeNextVisible": "Tue, 02 Apr 2019 19:03:32 GMT",
        "DequeueCount": "69",
        "MessageText": "{\"etag\":\"\",\"ItemInternalId\":\"ab5c-4859-a755\",\"LastChangeDate\":\"2019-04-02T13:37:32.9638012Z\",\"is_current_employee\":true}"
    }
```

This is causing me a massive headache when I go to try and use the body, especially when I pipe that raw MessageText to my Liquid Template. I tried the expression `json(triggerBody())` and that does not work, it fails because of the first "/". I tried to use the Parse JSON action, but that does not work because that is just designed to map the JSON to a schema and fails because `MessageText` is a string anyway.

- Is there a `JSON.parse(triggerBody())` equivalent? The docs do not
  show escaped JSON examples.
- Am I storing the JSON improperly?

I created a NodeJS Function to literally return a `JSON.parse()` with a JSON content type header. Which seems like a huge waste of resources.

**EDIT:** One solution I got working was to manually base64 encode when I add to queue and then `@json(decodeBase64(triggerBody()?['MessageText']))` when I pull from queue. The result works but wont that encode twice under the hood?

Comment: did you try with `json.stringify(..)` ?

Comment: @HimanshuAhuja That is not a real Azure Expression. And if it was, would simply double-escape my `MessageText` string. I need the azure `json` expression to handle escaped strings.

Comment: @VictorioBerra whether the messageText has a defined schema that you are aware or it is dynamic ?

Comment: @HariHaran The message in the queue is dynamic, we do not have a schema for it. Im not aware of how I can apply a schema to the queue. The goal is to pass the JSON to a liquid template for transformation.

Answer (score 1):

I am also trying to understand your question..I tried adding message to queue and retrieved in logic but I didn't see any such issue.. Did I miss anything ?

[image]

Message retrieved in logic app

[image]

I get output like this in email

```
{"ItemInternalId":"ab5c-4859-a755","LastChangeDate":"2019-04-02T13:37:32.9638012Z","is_current_employee":true}
```

Comment: Can you show me the raw input of the Send email? is the json escaped? Also, how is the message being base64 decoded? Is that done automatically by the trigger?

Comment: So, I have no idea what I did. But it seems to be working as expected now.